# c++ Некорректно отображается русский текст в командной строке

Tags: c++, visual-c++, locale

Код:

[image: Код]

При запуске программы через cmd отображается это:

[image: Вывод с setlocale]

Если из кода убрать setlocale то вывод будет совсем другой:

[image: Вывод без setlocale]

То есть он что-то делает но всё равно ничего не работает.

НО В САМОМ VS CODE ВСЁ ВЫВОДИТСЯ ОТЛИЧНО:

[image: вывод в vs code]

***Помогите, как это пофиксить чтоб через cmd всё нормально выводилось, я вообще щас с ума сойду***

Comment: Код лучше представлять в виде текста.